# ANSI escape sequences in compilation-mode

Tags: compile-mode, ansi

When you run various "modern" compilation or test tools you get ANSI codes in the output. I'd like to either render them correctly (ideally) or otherwise strip them. I've tried applying either `term-mode-hook` to the `compilation-minor-mode` as suggested in [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/416567/combine-compilation-mode-and-ansi-term-mode-in-emacs), and also a similar approach using `shell-mode` as per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450173/emacs-compile-python-vs-running-in-shell), to no avail.

Does anyone have this working?

Comment: http://endlessparentheses.com/ansi-colors-in-the-compilation-buffer-output.html ?

Comment: Ah, maybe the ansi codes aren't colours

Comment: Running the command from a shell in an `ansi-term` buffer, does it render correctly? (or in `shell-mode` for that matter, although the latter seems less likely). If so, show us your attempt to integrate the working one with `compilation-minor-mode` ?

Comment: Yes, but it turns out that's because past-me wrote a comint-mode preoutput filter to strip non-colour ansi sequences :) I'm going to see how to add that to compilation-mode and report back.

Comment: Great. It's always a nice feeling when past-you solves present-you's problems :)

Comment: I'm also very interested in the answer to this for sbt-mode https://github.com/ensime/emacs-sbt-mode/issues/100

Comment: The proper solution is to teach your tool *not* to print such sequences when run in a dumb shell.

Answer (score 10):

There are two parts to this. First, process ANSI colors :

```
;; Stolen from (http://endlessparentheses.com/ansi-colors-in-the-compilation-buffer-output.html)
(require 'ansi-color)
(defun endless/colorize-compilation ()
  "Colorize from `compilation-filter-start' to `point'."
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (ansi-color-apply-on-region
     compilation-filter-start (point))))

(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook
          #'endless/colorize-compilation)
```

Next, filter out unwanted ANSI escape sequences, like the ones intended for `tty`s but Emacs doesn't know/care about:

```
;; Stolen from (https://oleksandrmanzyuk.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/better-emacs-shell-part-i/)
(defun regexp-alternatives (regexps)
  "Return the alternation of a list of regexps."
  (mapconcat (lambda (regexp)
               (concat "\\(?:" regexp "\\)"))
             regexps "\\|"))

(defvar non-sgr-control-sequence-regexp nil
  "Regexp that matches non-SGR control sequences.")

(setq non-sgr-control-sequence-regexp
      (regexp-alternatives
       '(;; icon name escape sequences
         "\033\\][0-2];.*?\007"
         ;; non-SGR CSI escape sequences
         "\033\\[\\??[0-9;]*[^0-9;m]"
         ;; noop
         "\012\033\\[2K\033\\[1F"
         )))

(defun filter-non-sgr-control-sequences-in-region (begin end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char begin)
    (while (re-search-forward
            non-sgr-control-sequence-regexp end t)
      (replace-match ""))))

(defun filter-non-sgr-control-sequences-in-output (ignored)
  (let ((start-marker
         (or comint-last-output-start
             (point-min-marker)))
        (end-marker
         (process-mark
          (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))))
    (filter-non-sgr-control-sequences-in-region
     start-marker
     end-marker)))

(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
          'filter-non-sgr-control-sequences-in-output)
```

Note that the second part is actually getting applied to all `comint` derivatives, not just `compilation-mode` (It also fixes issues in, e.g. `shell`). If this is not what you want, then add the hook to `compilation-filter-hook` instead.